# ASM Space Usage

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, oracle-asm

Oracle Version: 12.1.0.2

I had about 100 GB freespace on my **+ASM** diskgroup on Friday.

When I came back on Monday, I see only 45 gigs. How can I find what consumed my space?

Or is there a SQLPlus command (or) TOAD method we can use?

**Your help is my salvation.**

Comment: `SQL Developer` might have some pre-built Reports that are useful.  How did you see "GB Free"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `asmcmd`, where you have `cd`, `ls` and `du`.

If you insist on doing this through SQL, then you can use views such as `V$ASM_ALIAS`, `V$ASM_FILE`, `V$ASM_DISKGROUP`.